# In which scenario do we use the Factory Pattern and in which the Singleton Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Please help me to understand the Factory pattern and the Singleton pattern, when we need to use the Factory pattern and when to use the Singleton pattern.

What is the main advantage/disadvantage of one over the other?

Any suggestion (explanation) will help me lot.

Comment: @Close Supported Person: Why this question is not real?

Comment: While it may be slightly out of scope, and a bit complex and mystifying, It's still worth mentioning that using a DI/IoC framework can mimic both behaviours creating Singleton-Patterned instances of objects or Spit them out like a factory. This way you can maintain high testability because you're de-coupled from your static singleton calls. Just my 2c

Comment: @Aren, unfortunately I don't think your comment will help the OP much, as you predicted.

Comment: @Mike: It may not help the OP, but it may help someone else who finds this question looking for something else. This is why i prefaced the comment with a disclaimer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do two very different things.

A Factory exists to create one or more copies of a class. It, or a method it exposes, can be provided to another class that needs the dependency, and the dependent class can call the factory method to get an instance.

A singleton exists to create one and ONLY one copy of a class. A reference to the class is obtained statically, but that reference can then be passed around as an instance, unlike a purely static class.

Comment: when we are using the Singleton pattern, only one instance of the class is created, that instance is common for all the users OR every user have own instance?

Comment: @Vijjendra - "common for all users" OR "every user have their own instance" depends whether your executing code is in the same process or not. It has nothing to do with "users". If your process is a web application, a singleton instance may be the only instance for all requests, but if your web server starts another worker/task process, there could be another singleton instance in the memory space for that process as well.

Comment: @Mike:Thanks, mike please explain the second part(web server) scenario.

Comment: @Vijjendra - That depends on your web server. Originally, your question was tagged with ASP.NET, so please read http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article821-beginners-guide-how-iis-process-aspnet-request-.aspx

Answer (score 3):

They're not very similar, and thus they don't have advantages over one another. If you're confused, read up first:

- [Singleton Pattern - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)
- [Factory Pattern - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Use the singleton pattern when you wish to only allow one instance of an object class to be instantiated.

Use the factory pattern when you need to abstract out the details of instantiation of your object's class.